# ng-bootstrap datepicker popup placement not changing

Tags: datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the placement option listed under input options for the NgbInputDatePicker.

I'd like to change the default bottom-left position of the popup datepicker, but when I try to use placement in the plunker example (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/datepicker/demos/popup/plnkr.html) It doesn't change the position of the popup.

I've tried:

adding [placement]="top" inside of the input tag:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
         name="dp" [placement]="top" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
```

I've also tried just placing it in the parent div:

```
<div class="input-group" placement="top">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
         name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
```

but neither seems to change the pop up position.  I'm new to Angular, so perhaps I just have the syntax wrong somehow?  I noticed other input APIs in the documentation that seemed to be used in this fashion so I thought it might work...

I'm using ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-beta.2, and Angular 4.3.4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a *binding to an expression* (`top` means *expression* in `[placement]="top"`) while I think that your intention is to use `"top"` constant. You can solve it using one of the 2 methods:

- `placement="top"` (preferred)
- `[placement]="'top'"` (notice additional quotes around `top`)

When specified properly the `placement` option works perfectly fine as illustrated in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NCNmpm3tlxapH4jZS08F?p=preview

Comment: Thanks!  It's funny, I thought I tried this but it wasn't working for me.  Do you have any issues using the "bottom" placement expressions?  I tried "bottom" and "bottom-right" in the plunker example, but they all seem to be positioned around bottom-left...

Comment: `bottom-right` seems fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/74TCVXhuPdf1njL5hyWq?p=preview

Comment: Ah, I wonder if we're seeing different behaviors in our browsers...  I would attach a screenshot but I don't think images are possible in comment.  Basically the popup position looks the same for me.  I'm using the latest Chrome browser 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit), on Mac OS 10.12.6.  I tried the plunker in Safari and it looked similar.  The calendar is always positioned around the bottom-left. For "bottom-right", the top right corner of the calendar widget is aligned below the right side of the input field, so it's not positioned below the button itself at all.  Is this expected?

Comment: It is expected. Positioning is done in reference to the `<input>` tag, not the `<button>` tag afterwards. This is because people can place calendar button wherever they want (or not have it at all, and open on focus, for example). We could probably think of some other mechanism, file an issue at https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues if you believe that things should be changed / improved.

Comment: Ah, of course.  That makes sense.  Thank you for explaining this.  I'll ponder my need for this and file a feature request to embed the popup in a button if it's desirable.